# How to pass array values into the mail class one by one

Tags: laravel, smtp, laravel-mail

I want to pass the values of array into the Mail class. I have this code where i get the emails.

**Getting Emails from Database**

```
$vendorsId = OrdersProduct::select('vendor_id')->where('order_id', $order_id)->pluck('vendor_id');

$vendorEmails = Admin::select('email')->whereIn('id', $vendorsId)->get()->toArray();
```

**Result**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "email" => "mxxxxx@gmail.com"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "email" => "myyyyy@gmail.com"
  ]
]
```

So i want to pass these email address into the mail class to send mail one by one, here below is the mail code

**Sending Emails**

```
$messageData = [

                'order_id' => $order_id,                  
            ];

Mail::send('emails.order', $messageData, function ($message) use ($email) {
                $message->to($email)->subject('Order Placed');
            });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use foreach?

```
            $email = Auth::user()->email;

            $messageData = [
                'email' => $email,
                'name' => Auth::user()->name,
                'order_id' => $order_id,
                'orderDetails' => $orderDetails,
            ];
    

           foreach ($vendorEmails as $vemail) {
               Mail::send('emails.order', $messageData, function ($message) use ($email, $vemail) 

           {
                    $message->to($vemail)->subject('Order Placed - stylooworld.info');
                });
           }
```

Comment: Dear @nick now it show an error 
TypeError
Illegal offset type

Comment: Try $message->to($vemail['email'])->subject('Order Placed - stylooworld.info');

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this ;

```
$emailList = Admin::->whereIn('id', $vendorsId)->pluck('email')->toArray();

Mail::send('emails.order', $messageData, function ($message) use ($emailList) {
                $message->to($emailList)->subject('Order Placed');
            });
```